# How update element array in mongodb with mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a document structure like this

```
 username : String,
    notification:{
       id:String,username:String,desc:String,created: Date,status:Boolean,flag:String
    },
```

sample data

```js
"notification" : [
                {
                        "status" : true,
                        "created" : ISODate("2017-05-24T06:41:55.735Z"),
                        "desc" : "kamu baru saja mendapatkan pesan dari GILANG",
                      
                        "username" : "GILANG",
                        "id" : "141ee270-404c-11e7-a6a0-fb6a792329ad"
                },
```

Inside Robomongo, I use this query successfully

```
db.getCollection('members').update( {'notification.id':'141ee270-404c-11e7-a6a0-fb6a792329ad'},
        { $set:{'notification.$.status':false} }
```

)

Then I use mongoose the query did not work

```js
 member.update({'notification.id':id},
    {'$set':
        {
          'notification.$.status':false

        }
    }, (err,data) => {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
         callback({"message":err,"status":"error","statuscode":"400"})
      } else {
        console.log(`success delete notification${id}`);
          callback({"message":data,"status":"success","statuscode":"200"});
      }

    });
```

in my package.json like this

```
"dependencies": {
"body-parser": "~1.17.1",
"cookie-parser": "~1.4.3",
"debug": "~2.6.3",
"ejs": "~2.5.6",
"express": "~4.15.2",
"mongoose": "^4.9.9",
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is in your schema. Try changing notification schema definition from object to array:

```
notification:[{
       id:String,username:String,desc:String,created: Date,status:Boolean,flag:String
    }],
```